# Are there situations where rel2abs($0) returns somthing different than rel2abs(__FILE__)?

Tags: perl, path, executable

Are there situations where these two says (`rel2abs($0)` and `rel2abs(__FILE__)`) return something different?

```
use 5.10.0;
use File::Spec::Functions qw(rel2abs);

say rel2abs($0);

say rel2abs(__FILE__);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As *tripleee* mentioned, a program may consist of multiple `__FILE__`s.
2. The `$0` may be set to anything (depends on the OS):

   ```
   $0 = "foo bar";
   ```

Instead of using `rel2abs`, you might be interested in the [`FindBin`](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin) module, especially the `$FindBin::RealBin` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If `$0` is not `__FILE__`, they are different. This could happen if you `require` or `use` or `do` this file from another script.